# LSTM Binary Classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

I have a dataset that contains the weather features of past 4 days (4 features), 1 output `extreme`, which indicates whether the weather is extreme or not which is binary (0=not extreme, 1=extreme weather) and I am trying to predict the next days extreme value (0 or 1).

Since this is a time series binary classification problem I want to use an algorithm which is a classification and time series algorithm and I thought LSTM would be a good fit. After researching online I could not find any good examples and I am having hard time to make binary classification with LSTM.

This is `x_train`:

```
Date                    Station 32      33      34

10/09/2019 12:00:00 AM  D5      20.6    85.0    962.1

10/09/2019 12:00:00 AM  WU      21.1    81.0    1003.7
```

This is `y_train`:

```
0       0

1       1

2       1

3       0

4       1
```

This is the model:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
```

And this is the error I get:

```
ValueError: Please provide as model inputs either a single array or a list of arrays.
You passed: x=                        Date Station    32    33      34

0     10/09/2019 12:00:00 AM      D5  20.6  85.0   962.1

2     10/09/2019 12:00:00 AM      WU  21.1  81.0  1003.7

5     10/09/2019 12:00:00 AM      X4  22.2  83.0  1004.8

6     10/09/2019 12:00:00 AM      X8  23.5  78.0   999.2

8     10/09/2019 12:30:00 AM      D5  19.3  90.0   961.7

...                      ...     ...   ...   ...     ...

1680  14/09/2019 09:00:00 AM      D5  25.4  46.0   978.9

1682  14/09/2019 09:00:00 AM      WU  24.8  56.0  1021.6

1685  14/09/2019 09:00:00 AM      X4  25.5  49.0  1022.1

1686  14/09/2019 09:00:00 AM      X8  25.8  47.0  1016.7

1688  14/09/2019 09:30:00 AM      D5  24.8  47.0   978.9

[845 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: There are [examples](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series) in the official Tensorflow documentation for multivariate time series forecasting. Also you can't just pass a non-processed pandas dataframe into an LSTM.

Comment: But those examples are not for classification but for prediction of values.

Comment: Yes. But you can easily change that.

Comment: Well I couldn't do that, thats why I am asking a question here.

Comment: Well let me know when you're at the end of the tutorial and ready to fit the model. I'll be able to help then if you have a specific question.

Comment: The error message is clear. You need to pass a list or equivalent as input. Instead you passed a DataFrame.